# Where to get domu images for quick deployment

Tags: xen, image, amazon-ami

I'm looking for a place where I can get prebuilt xen domu images like the readymade AMI's that amazon provides for quick deployment, but freely available to integrate into non EC2 environments.

Do You have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked [Stacklet](http://stacklet.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [Xen-tools](http://xen-tools.noone.org/software/xen-tools/) that installs distributions on the fly ?